# ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed error when I am using ngx-progress in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am using [ngx-progressbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-progressbar) bar in Angular 2 application. When app loading first it is working fine. second time it is showing error. I referred few article like [medium.com](https://medium.com/@fsufitch/angular-2-objectunsubscribederror-woes-abda60e04cfe) for subscribe object. I did't get clearly.
I need to make progress bar every time when click the router links.

**I attached error snapshot:**
[image]

**progress bar code:**

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NgProgress } from 'ngx-progressbar'
@Component({
  selector: 'link-outlet',
  template: '<ng-progress [showSpinner]="false"></ng-progress>'
})
export class RoutingDirectiveComponent implements AfterContentInit{
  constructor(private ngProgress: NgProgress) {

  }
  ngAfterContentInit(){

   this.ngProgress.start();
   setTimeout(()=>{
     this.ngProgress.done();
   }, 2000);
  }
 }
```

Your suggestion will be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because the component that holds the progressbar is being destroyed while the progressbar is running, so you should put `<ng-progress></ng-progress>` in a root component (or a component that does not get destroyed)

If you are using the progress for router change event there is a feature module [NgProgressRouterModule](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar/wiki/Router-events)

If you are using the progress for http requests there is a feature module [NgProgressHttpModule](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar/wiki/HttpClient-requests)

#### Update

Since v2.1.1, you can use the component anywhere without getting that error

Comment: Thanks for your response. could you please give some example to create that in root component or any article or links to do that.

Comment: @MathankumarK Just add `<ng-progress></ng-progress>` in AppComponent template, and start/stop the progress using `NgProgressService` anywhere in your app

Answer (score 102):

#### Updated - Angular 8

This answer is still valid syntactically for Angular 8.

---

I realize this is an old post, we're on Angular 6 now, I believe. However, I got this error and wanted to post a solution.

I had this problem when I called `.unsubscribe()` directly on the object that I had called `.subscribe()` on. However, when you subscribe to an event, that method hands back a `Subscription` typed value. You need to save this (possibly on your component's class), then call unsubscribe on **that Subscription object** when you're done.

**Examples**

Bad Code:

```
this.someEvent.subscribe(() => {
    // DO SOMETHING
})
...
this.someEvent.unsubscribe()
```

Good Code:

```
this.myEventSubscription = this.someEvent.subscribe(() => {
     // DO SOMETHING
})
...
this.myEventSubscription.unsubscribe()
```

Again, you need to unsubscribe from the `Subscription` object that the `.subscribe()` method returns when you call it.

Comment: this is great, i wasn't even realizing i was doing that, awesome thanks

Comment: A nice show of unsubscribing to the subscription,  rather than the event.

Comment: i don't know why this answer is not on top

Answer (score 10):

I really liked the way @kbpontius told, so I am also doing the same approach

Whenever you subscribe, subscribe in the new variable. So after unsubscribe it can be subscribed
Examples

Bad Code:

```
this.someEvent.subscribe(() => {
    // DO SOMETHING
})
...

ngOnDestroy() {
     this.someEvent.unsubscribe()
}
```

Good Code:

Declare the event name

```
myEventSubscription: any;
```

//Now it can be use like this

```
this.myEventSubscription = this.someEvent.subscribe(() => {
     // DO SOMETHING
})
```

...

//Now unsubcribe this in last phase of destroying component.
You can destroy in other function too if you want to destroy the service in the same component

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.myEventSubscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

Again, you need to unsubscribe from the Subscription object that the .subscribe() method returns when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, I was using BehaviorSubject and it always saves the last response there are 2 solution for it.

1. Use Subject instead of BehaviorSubject
2. Simply add the below
   line inside the subscription.

   `<your service>.next(undefined);`

Also remember to unsubscribe the subscriptions that you have created manually.

I hope this helps.